# In Xcode, my instagram app cannot get url callback

Tags: xcode, url, instagram

I am taking a Coursera class and have followed the instructors code verbatim.  However, upon logging in to Instagram, I am sent to a website and not my example app I am trying to use.

Comment: Can't help if you don't post any code...

Answer (score 0):

I assume the course is not built for iOS 9+.

From iOS 9, you needs to provide a LSApplicationQueriesSchemes entry in its plist file, declaring which schemes it attempts to query.

```
 <key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
   <array>
     <string>instagram</string>
   </array> 
</key>
```